# pybind11 with C++ that needs linking with static library

Tags: pybind11, pybinding

I apologize in advance if this is obvious.
We are investigating using pybind to bind Python to our C++ code.  Everything seems to work fine until we have discovered a problem.  Our software builds and links with various static libraries (mostly stubs that load various DLLs like Intel IPP).

To clarify the problem, the C++ code makes calls to functions in libraries, and I can't figure out how to link these libraries with pybind11, so that the code in the libraries is available.

I have poured through the documentation and through stack overflow and simply cannot find how to do this.

If this is not obvious and easy to answer, I can supply a MWE, if needed.

Comment: How are you building your python extensions? With a setup.py or something else?